# Fail to start pycharm desktop entry

Tags: pycharm

First start pyCharm from it's bin folder via command line

$ sudo ./pycharm.sh

Then, goto

Tools -> Create Desktop Entry. 
But,I click icon can`t start pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal and run:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/

ls
```

Find desktop file name with pycharm like 'pycharm.desktop', then:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/pycharm.desktop
```

If it doesn't exist, a blank one will be created.

Check in Gedit if there are following lines(paste these if not or blank text was created):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PyCharm
Exec=PATH_TO_PYCHARM_DIR/bin/pycharm.sh
Icon=PATH_TO_PYCHARM_DIR/bin/PyCharm.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application
StartupWMClass=PyCharm
Terminal=false
```

Change PATH_TO_PYCHARM_DIR with correct path to pycharm bin directory